# How do I defeat an enemy with every resistance?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

Orthog Pain-Lover has been giving me a lot of trouble. He and his goons of spear-throwing hunters killed me a couple times, and it seems he's managed to get every resistance. I can't damage him with:

- Melee attacks
- Ranged attacks
- Steal Attacks
- Draining

He's not immune to monsters, but I've seen him 1-hit caragors (that's part of how he got so powerful; multiple Beast Hunt events), so I don't feel great about that approach.

How do I kill Orthog?

[image: Orthog]

Comment: Have you tried burning him?

Comment: @DevanLoper I don't think there is a reliable way to burn him tho, maybe with exploding campfires, but it is going to be tough.

Comment: "Pain-Lover" indeed...

Comment: I have burned him - that's the only way I've dealt damage to him. But he became terrified and he managed to escape (since I can't pin him with my bow).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If an enemy is feared, their strengths will be lessened or negated.

In the case of Orthog, blowing up two nearby campfires when a feast event came up panicked him, and I could damage him with melee attacks in that state.

Pictures for those who want to relish in victory:
[image: Subdued]

[image: Sub-dead]

Comment: Often, I've found that captains can be immediately grabbed if they're afraid and fleeing. I'm not sure if this is always the case though.

Comment: It's not always the case but it's often. If a captain has a green icon it means they should be grab-able. But I've had captains with green icons that knock me off them when I grab.

Comment: I have also read (but been unable to test for myself yet) that those resistances only apply to YOU. This means you can dominate other uruk and have them weaken the big baddie to the point where you can grab him and deal with him as you please.

Comment: @AdamP I can pretty confidently confirm that this is the case. - One of my captains just killed one of these guys with a spear (it might have been poison damage though; more tests are needed)

Comment: Now, what do you do when he has no vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

even if he does have vulnerability to everything, blowing up two campfires, making him run away, and then shadow strike should work. Even if the shadow strike does no damage, it will still teleport you to him, allowing you to grab him. Be sure you have enough arrows to do this.

Comment: This seems a lot like a comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options that I see:

1. Either find a graug ride it to him and attack
2. Explode some grog or a campfire and while he is running grab him and then either kill him or dominate him (Option 1 only works if you can dominate a graug).